# Angular 2: get image from file upload

Tags: angular, ng2-bootstrap

Hi in my Angular 2 app I am using ng2-file-upload:

```
<input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" multiple (change)="onChange($event)">
```

I would like to create an instance of **image** object in my javascript code from **uploader** or the **event** object. Somehow like:

```
public onChange(event) {
   let item = this.uploader.queue[0];
   let img = new Image();

   img.src = item.SOMETHING;
       OR
   img.src = event.SOMETHING;

}
```

I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: What's the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that without any third-party library.

**helloworld.component**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  // Declare the tag name in index.html to where the component attaches
  selector: 'hello-world',

  // Location of the template for this component
  templateUrl: 'src/hello_world.html',
  styles: [`
    .preview img{
      max-height: 50px;
    }
  `]
})
export class HelloWorld {

  // Declaring the variable for binding with initial value
  yourName: string = '';

  fileChange(event) {
    let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;
    if(fileList.length > 0) {
      let file: File = fileList[0];
      var img = document.querySelector("#preview img");
      img.file = file;

      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (function(aImg) { return function(e) { aImg.src = e.target.result; }; })(img);
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  }
}
```

**src/hello_world.html**

```
<div id="preview" class="preview">
  <img src="">
</div>
<form>
  <input type="file" (change)="fileChange($event)" placeholder="Upload file">
</form>
```

[Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IeC2AMup7OsBufqM2iwD?p=preview)

Comment: `img.file` is giving me an error "file does not exist on type Element" using Angular 5

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with 
[ng2-file-upload](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload) also.check below code

component code:

```
    import { DomSanitizer, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { FileUploader } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';
    import { FileItem } from 'ng2-file-upload';

    @Component({
       selector: 'app-image',
       templateUrl: './image.component.html',
       styleUrls : []
    })
    export class ImageComponent implements OnInit {

      public imageUrlPath: SafeUrl;
      public uploader: FileUploader;
      constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer ){
           this.uploader = new FileUploader({
                allowedMimeType: [],
                maxFileSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, // 10 MB
            });
            this.uploader.onAfterAddingFile = (fileItem) => {
                  fileItem.withCredentials = false;
                  this.imageUrlPath  = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl((window.URL.createObjectURL(fileItem._file)));
             };
       }
   ngOnInit(){}    

    }
```

html code:

```
 <input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader">
  <div>
   <img *ngIf="imageUrlPath" [src] = imageUrlPath>              
 </div>
```

follow this link:[image preview](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/issues/158), [image directive](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload/issues/461)